# Get all user installed packages at a specific point in dnf history

Tags: fedora, rpm, command-history, dnf

Using the command `dnf history` I'm able to list all dnf transactions since my system's installation.

How would I go about listing all user installed packages that were installed at a specific point in the dnf transaction history by transaction ID? Something akin to the `dnf history userinstalled` command except for at the point of a specific transaction.

Comment: Is there something unclear from the [dnf command documentation](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#history-command)?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I would want something like `dnf history userinstalled` but at the point of a specific transaction, however I don't see how I would do this going by the documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure what output you want exactly, but is this something close `for pkg in $(dnf history userinstalled | tail -n +2) ; do echo $pkg ; dnf history $(rpm -q $pkg --qf '%{Name}') ; done'`?

Comment: You can also check the rpm install time for a package.  For example, `date --date="@$(rpm -q zstd-1.4.2-1.fc29.x86_64 --qf '%{Installtid}')"`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I would like a list of **all** packages I had done a `dnf install` for at the point of a specific transaction ID. I'll try playing around with what you wrote and see if that works for me.